# RecyclerView smoothScroolToPositionFromTop()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any alternatives to ListView's [smoothScrollToPositionFromTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(int,%20int)) for RecyclerView? I am trying to migrate the ListView code to RecyclerView, and I don't see the RecyclerView version of that anywhere.

There is one method called [RecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int)) , but you cannot define the offset to that relative to the top element of the screen (I need the list to scroll to a position, and always stop when the position is the first visible child in the List).

Comment: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/scrolling-recyclerview-part-3/  hope this artice is helpful to you

Comment: For recyclerview, the responsibility falls on the `LayoutManager`. Have a look at this https://mcochin.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/android-customizing-smoothscroller-for-the-recyclerview/ for some inspiration but if you google around, you'll find many other implementations as well.

Comment: Update: I ended up changing my design to achieve the same result, with a different visual.

Answer (score 1):

To smooth scroll the target position always to the top you can use a custom LinearLayoutManager like that:

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
    private Context context;

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {
        LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {

            @Override
            public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                return CustomLinearLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
            }

            @Override
            protected int getVerticalSnapPreference() {
                return SNAP_TO_START;
            }
        };

        smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
        startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use     mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);

Comment: That doesn't smooth scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                }
            }, 600);
```